# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

```
cat_features = train_data.dtypes[train_data.dtypes == 'object'].index
ohe = OneHotEncoder(cat_features, handle_unknown='ignore')

ohe.fit_transform(train_data)
```

results in

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing an array with a string, but numpy can only can compare elemments of an array individually. So numpy returns an array of boolean values.

Now it is up to you if you want to make sure `.any()` element is `True` or `.all()` elements are `True`.

If you are trying to get the indices of the elements which are of type `'object'`, try a list comprehension:

```
cat_features = [td for td in train_data if td.dtype == 'object']
```

This gives you a list of all elements of `train_data` that are of type `'object'`.